# Symfony 3 - How inject own variable from config to service right way?

Tags: symfony, service, config

I want on my web create cache config with different cache values. I have working example:

```
// config.yml
parameters:
    myValue:
        first: 1
        second: 2

// services.yml
my_repo:
    class:  AppBundle\Repository\MyRepository
    factory: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", getRepository]
    arguments:
        - 'AppBundle\Entity\My'
    calls:
        - [setValue, ["%myValue%"]]

// MyRepository.php
public function setValue($val) {
    $this->first = $val['first'];
}

// Inside controller method
$someVariable = $this->get('my_repo')
    ->someOtherFunction();
```

But is this way correct? What if another programmer will call repository 'standart' way `$em->getRepository('MyRepository')`? It will crash on udefined variable... Is there way to do this for example via constructor? Or constructor is bad idea?

I am interested in the yours practice - better solution etc.

Comment: Why do you want to make this repository as service? Why don't you create a service and pass entity manager to it?

Comment: Because i want have config file where i will have config values like cache, max results, max displayed categories and so on... And access to this config is only from controller but not from repository.

Comment: I think it's better to make a service for storage, call it MessageStorage for example, and let it manage retrieving data and caching, pagination etc...

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
 [setValue, ["@=container.hasParameter('myValue') ? parameter('myValue') : array()"]]
```

Should do the trick. Then just check in your service if the variable injected is empty or not. See [the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/expression_language.html) for more on the Expression language